# How to estimate how much GPU memory required for deep learning?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, nvidia

We are trying to train our model for object recognition using tensorflow. Since there are too many images (100GB), I guess our current GPU server (1*2080Ti) could not work. We may need to purchase a more powerful one, but I do not sure how to estimate how much GPU memory we need. Is there some approach to estimate the requirements? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 2080Ti would do just fine for your task. The GPU memory for DL tasks are dependent on many factors such as number of trainable parameters in the network, size of the images you are feeding, batch size, floating point type (FP16 or FP32) and number of activations and etc. I think you get confused about loading all of the images to GPU memory at once. We do not do that, instead we use minibatches of different sizes to fit all of the images and params into memory. Throw any kind of network to your 2080Ti and adjust batch size then your training will run smoothly. You could go with your 2080Ti or can get another or two increase training speed. [This](https://timdettmers.com/2019/04/03/which-gpu-for-deep-learning/) blogpost provides beautiful insights about creating optimal DL environments.